# Select Box returning to original state when selecting?

Tags: php, html

In the following form i have the options in the select box appending to the url. However i would like to change this to the submit button instead since the user will enter username and select the dropdown value.

```html
        <section id="search">
            <form method="get" action="index.php" id="main-form">

                <div class="summoner_search">
                    <input id="summoner" name="summoner" type="text" placeholder="Summoner"/>
                    <input id="region" name="region" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $region ?>"/>
                    <input id="form" name="form" type="hidden" value="true"/>

                    <select id="regions" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
                      <option value="index.php?region=br">BR</option>
                      <option value="index.php?region=eune">EUNE</option>
                      <option value="index.php?region=euw">EUW</option>
                      <option value="index.php?region=kr">KR</option>
                      <option value="index.php?region=lan">LAN</option>
                      <option value="index.php?region=las">LAS</option>
                      <option value="index.php?region=na">NA</option>
                      <option value="index.php?region=oce">OCE</option>
                      <option value="index.php?region=ru">RU</option>
                      <option value="index.php?region=tr">TR</option>
                    </select>

                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="display:none;"/>        
                </div>
                <a href="index.php" alt="reset">Reset Values</a>
            </form>
        </section>
```

Currently the dropdown refreshes the page and the summoner name has to be reentered. If i can place this to the submit button so the value will append after submit i think it should be better but i dont know how to do that.

Another side query i had was can someone please point me in the right direction to auto load the dropdown value based on what country is accessing?

Thanks 
Alex

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid having to enter the summoner value again after the onchange event of your select fires, then you could append the summoner input's value to the URL that is called in that onchange event, similar to the following code:

```
<section id="search">
    <form method="get" action="index.php" id="main-form">
        <div class="summoner_search">
            <input id="summoner" name="summoner" type="text" 
                   placeholder="Summoner"
                   value="<?php echo htmlentities($_GET['summoner'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>"
                   />
            <input id="region" name="region" type="hidden"
                   value="<?php echo htmlentities($region, ENT_QUOTES); ?>"
                   />
            <input id="form" name="form" type="hidden" value="true"/>

            <script>
                function load(select) {
                    var summoner = document.getElementById('summoner');
                    var url = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
                    if (summoner.value) {
                        url += '&' + encodeURIComponent(summoner.value);
                    }
                    window.location.href = url;
                }
            </script>
            <select id="regions" onchange="load(this);">
                <option value="index.php?region=br">BR</option>
                <option value="index.php?region=eune">EUNE</option>
                <option value="index.php?region=euw">EUW</option>
                <option value="index.php?region=kr">KR</option>
                <option value="index.php?region=lan">LAN</option>
                <option value="index.php?region=las">LAS</option>
                <option value="index.php?region=na">NA</option>
                <option value="index.php?region=oce">OCE</option>
                <option value="index.php?region=ru">RU</option>
                <option value="index.php?region=tr">TR</option>
            </select>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="display:none;"/>

        <a href="index.php" alt="reset">Reset Values</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
```

> If i can place this to the submit button so the value will append after submit i think it should be better but i dont know how to do that.

Do you mean that you want to send both a summoner parameter (your summoner input's value) and a region parameter (your region-select's value) when the submit button is clicked?
Then you can simply change your select to:

```
<select name="region">
    <option value="br">BR</option>
    <option value="eune">EUNE</option>
    ....
</select>
```

Then your index.php will receive both a summoner and a region value upon sending the form.

> Another side query i had was can someone please point me in the right direction to auto load the dropdown value based on what country is accessing?

You would need a geolocation library for that. Use that to detect the region of the visitor from his or her IP address. Then pick from your set of available regions the one that is closest to the visitor's region und mark the related option in the select as `selected`.